# Thoughts on creating vertical drawer for mobile web with drag feature in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, drawer

I want to create a drawer in mobile web, which will bleed till x position and user can be dragged up or down the drawer.
Creating drawer and adding basic animation was easy in CSS

```
// close
  transform: translateY(calc(100% - 300px));
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;

// open
    transform: translateY(60px);
```

Now as per my knowledge, we cannot use drag events in mobile view since it is not supported and touch events will not help a lot.
is there any way I can implement this in react?